# Mongoose exclude documents that contain specific nested object in array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, find, nor

I have collection of objects similar to this (simplified for the purpose of this question):

```
_id: '6509e5f504613ddc1d92c62f',
matchingHistory: [
  {
    color: 'red',
    shape: 'square',
    size: 'large',
    _id: '1509e5f504613ddc1d92c62g',
    updatedAt: '2023-09-21T16:16:00.000Z'
  },
  {
    color: 'red',
    shape: 'square',
    size: 'small',
    _id: '2509e5f504613ddc1d92c62h',
    updatedAt: '2023-09-21T16:10:00.000Z'
  },
]
```

I want to EXCLUDE all the documents from the `find` query that don't have in `matchingHistory` an object that is `red`, `square` and `large` but ALL and only ALL these conditions must match. Having said that, additionally, I'd like to ignore specific fields from search, such as `_id` and `updatedAt`. `matchingHistory` is initially not set and when reset later it becomes empty array, so those documents should be included in results. TLDR; I only want to EXCLUDE documents that contain an exact object (red + square + large) in the array of objects.

I have tried multiple combinations of `$not`, `$nor`, but they don't produce the expected results.

My last attempt was the below but the problem is, it actually also excludes "red + square + **small**" (as it seems to care about "at least" one property match:

```
$or: [
  {
    matchingHistory: {
      $exists: true,
      $eq: [],
    },
  },
  {
    matchingHistory: {
      $exists: false,
    },
  },
  {
    $and: [
      {
        matchingHistory.color: {
          $ne: 'red',
        },
      },
      {
        matchingHistory.shape: {
          $ne: 'square',
        },
      },
      {
        matchingHistory.size: {
          $ne: 'large',
        },
      },
    ],
  }
]
```

Comment: Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nCTDM-HX-qz) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly straightforward find. Just imagine you *want* to find the documents with a `matchingHistory` that has within it's array an object matching `{ color: 'red', shape: 'square', size: 'large'}` and then negate it like so:

**Mongosh Shell**

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {
      matchingHistory: {
        $exists: true,
        $eq: []
      }
    },
    {
      matchingHistory: {
        $exists: false
      }
    },
    {
      matchingHistory: {
        $not: {              //< All important not
          $elemMatch: {      //< Exact element match
            color: "red",
            shape: "square",
            size: "large"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}, {'matchingHistory._id': 0, 'matchingHistory.updatedAt': 0 });
```

**Node Driver:**

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {
      matchingHistory: {
        $exists: true,
        $eq: []
      }
    },
    {
      matchingHistory: {
        $exists: false
      }
    },
    {
      matchingHistory: {
        $not: {              //< All important not
          $elemMatch: {      //< Exact element match
            color: "red",
            shape: "square",
            size: "large"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}).project({
   'matchingHistory._id': 0, 
   'matchingHistory.updatedAt': 0 
});
```

Comment: I think I should probably modify my question slightly because even though your solution works perfectly for the question I asked, I forgot to mention that the object has additional properties that I simply don't want to care about... for example, apart from `color`, `shape`, `size`, it has also `_id`, `updatedAt` and few more properties... Do you know how to construct a query so it ignores them?

Comment: So you don't want these other properties output in the returned documents, i.e suppressed? If so that can be done in your output projection. I can give an example if you need?

Comment: The Node [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) show using a projection as a method chained to find but the Mongosh docs show the projection as the second parameter to the find method. I have included both examples in the answer above. Just add properties you want to excluded to suit your needs.

Comment: I don't want to hide anything from response, I want to ignore these values in query. something like:
{
      matchingHistory: {
        $not: {
          $elemMatch: {
            color: "red",
            shape: "square",
            size: "large",
            _id: *,
            _updatedAt: *
          }
        }
      }
    }

Comment: I will modify my original question to accommodate this

Comment: Sorry, my misunderstanding. The query will ignore those other properties. The `$elemMatch` in the answer only makes an exact match on those included in the answer. The other properties can have any value and the query will just ignore them.

Comment: This is interesting, in such case I must be doing something wrong on the different part of my query (it's quite complex and this is just small portion of it). I will run some tests later and let you know if it works. Btw, thank you for your help! 

Comment: See [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WS53nhoCgMM) I have added arbitrary properties and they make no difference to the query.

Comment: Thank you for your solution and help, turned out I had a slightly different response in one edge case due to a bug that wasn't covered by the test.

Comment: No problem. In my experience when a `find` in mongodb starts becoming too hard for me to logically hold the cases in my head I reach for [aggregate](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/). You write a stage, get your documents and then pass the results through to the next stage like a series of filters or layers. Very powerful.